# Merge some columns of a csv file depending on a condition

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file, that looks like this:

```
5005284;5003485;C1; C2;A00.00;10-11-01;NULL;1;;
2006483;2003855;this is some text; and some 787; or even &[]\><;A87.03;30-09-86;NULL;1;
2006485;2003855;C;K86.00;31-12-91;NULL;1;;;
```

The file is `;` separated and unfortunately, they used this character in 3rd column creating extra columns. I want to concatenate all these *false* columns into a single column as shown in expected output below.

So far, I have:

```
import re 
import pandas as pd

text = open ('testepisodes.csv')
cleared = pd.DataFrame()

for line in text:
# get rid of extra ;;; or ;;
    line.replace(";;;", ";")
    line.replace(";;", ";")
    print line
    index = line.count(";")
    print index
    if index==9:
        line = re.sub(r'^((?:[^.]*\;){4}[^.]*)\..*', r'\1', line)
    if index==8:
        line = re.sub(r'^((?:[^.]*\;){3}[^.]*)\..*', r'\1', line)
print line
```

Resulting in:

```
2078915;2003855;this is some text; and some 787; or even &[]\><;A87.03;30-09-86;NULL;1;
126
126
2078915;2003855;this is some text; and some 787; or even &[]\><;A87.03;30-09-86;NULL;1;
```

Where I'd like to have:

```
5005284;5003485;C1 C2;A00.00;10-11-01;NULL;1;
2006483;2003855;this is some text and some 787 or even &[]\><;A87.03;30-09-86;NULL;1;
2006485;2003855;C;K86.00;31-12-91;NULL;1;
```

---

**Edited from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017887/merge-some-columns-of-a-csv-file-depending-on-a-condition/38018902#comment63478895_38017887)**

Index 2 is always the starting point of what should be together. The new index 3 should contain 'A00.00' pattern where 'A' denotes any capital letter (A-Z), and each '0' denotes a digit (0-9).

Comment: Can you say what you actually want? Is it to remove all instances of more than one ";" and then write to file?

Comment: Also, I can't reproduce the problem. I'm getting `print index` as `9`.

Comment: Will C ever occur outside of index 2 (Column C you called it, I assume in your spreadsheet program)?

Comment: Index 2 is always the starting point of what should be together. The new index 3 should contain 'A00.000' (or the code after the string).

Comment: I see one problem: the end of the line is not found, importing the csv and printing the first line gives: python cleanepisodes.py 
2078915;2003855;this is some text and some 787 or even &[]\<>;;A87.03;30-09-86;NULL;1;ULL;1;;;L;1;;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import csv
import re


with open('file.csv') as f, open('newfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as newf:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    writer = csv.writer(newf, delimiter=';')

    rows = []
    for row in reader:
        for i, e in enumerate(row):
            if re.match('[A-Z][0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}', e): # looking for pattern "A00.00"
                idx = i
                break
        newrow = row[:2]
        newrow.append(' '.join(e.strip() for e in row[2:idx])) # joining columns that should be together
        newrow += row[idx:]
        writer.writerow([e for e in newrow if e]) # writing only non-empty columns


with open('newfile.csv') as f:
    for row in f:
        print(row)
```

With input file like this:

```
5005284;5003485;C1; C2;A00.00;10-11-01;NULL;1;;
2006483;2003855;this is some text; and some 787; or even &[]\><;A87.03;30-09-86;NULL;1;
2006485;2003855;C;K86.00;31-12-91;NULL;1;;;
```

output file created looks like this:

```
5005284;5003485;C1 C2;A00.00;10-11-01;NULL;1
2006483;2003855;this is some text and some 787 or even &[]\><;A87.03;30-09-86;NULL;1
2006485;2003855;C;K86.00;31-12-91;NULL;1
```

Note that there is no `;` at the end of each line which is the usual case in csv file. However, if you want that, add an empty column at the end of each row while writing to the new file. Maybe like this:

```
writer.writerow([e for e in newrow if e] + [''])
```

Answer (score 0):

## Removing ";"

`line.replace()` does not change the original line, it returns a new line with the requested changes.  See documentation [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm)  Therefore, this code is not doing what you think it is:

```
line.replace(";;;", ";")
line.replace(";;", ";")
```

Example:

```
a
Out[20]: ';fsdfds;dsfss;f;sdfsdf;sdf'

a.replace("s", "S")
Out[21]: ';fSdfdS;dSfSS;f;SdfSdf;Sdf'

a
Out[22]: ';fsdfds;dsfss;f;sdfsdf;sdf'
```

Try something like this instead:

```
while ";;" in line:
    line = line.replace(";;", ";")
```

This will remove any duplicates of the ";" character.

## Writing to .csv

Try something like

```
with open("new_document.csv") as new:
   new.write(modified_lines)
```

## Improving the structure:

A better way to do this is to use a generator to filter and fix the lines in the csv, then iterate over it to write to a new file.  Example:

```
def fix_wonky_csv(wonky_csv):
    for line in wonky_csv:
        # fix the lines
        yield line

def create_new_file:
    newfile = open(new_title, "w")
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in fix_wonky_csv(f):
            newfile.write(line)
    newfile.close()
```

Comment: He's looking to concat the information that should be in list index 2 from indexes 2->x. This is not an replacement question